# Изучение ООП студентом

Tags: ооп

При изучении ООП приходится разбираться в достаточно сложных понятиях.

Чисто теоретический вопрос:

Насколько глубоко *начинающий* программист должен знать теорию?

---

Понятно, что основополагающие принципы он знать обязан.

Наследование, Инкапсуляция, Полиморфизм.

Должен понимать основные концепции программирования.

Класс, Объект, Динамические элементы, Статические элементы, Абстракция, Интерфейсы...

Но вот дальше?

Насколько необходимы ему знания по UML, отличия разных языков программирования, другие тонкости?

Какие, по вашему мнению, знания абсолютно необходимы начинающему программисту для того, чтобы начать выдавать что-то реально полезное?

---

Если вопрос не заинтересовал, то дальше можно не читать.

Мне приходилось набирать программистов в свою команду.

Разброс теоретических знаний у студентов иногда отличается просто кардинально.

Ну понятно, что совсем нерадивых, которые не могут отличить статический метод от динамического, отсеиваем сразу.

Но дальше... По моему опыту, объем тех дополнительных *специфических* знаний, который принятый на работу студент обязан изучить перед началом реальной работы достаточно большой. И это отнюдь не "композиция", "агрегация" или ассоциация". На моей практике за 30 лет программирования знание таких понятий пригодилось всего пару раз! Может быть я просто работал не в тех конторах, где это необходимо...

Здесь на форуме и в других местах часто вижу вопросы, которые задают явно совсем студенты, которые еще не понимают даже основ, а лезут в дебри, которые совсем и не пригодятся в жизни. На практике, чаще всего, необходимо знание предметной области, чем какие-то теоретические знания как какой элемент называется в теории. Понятно, что общие понятия о наличии того или иного способа взаимодействия нужно знать. Но конкретно изучать и пытаться изучить сферического коня в вакууме, чаще всего, совершенно бесполезно.

В дальнейшем, при наличии уже достаточно солидного опыта программирования, уже можно начать докапываться до сути разных терминов... Особенно, если стоит задача **спроектировать** достаточно сложную систему. Для того чтобы суметь рассказать суть другим....

Возможно, я ошибаюсь.
Поэтому и задаю вопрос.

Comment: Единственное что могу порекомендовать на эту тему — статью Джоэла Спольски (одного из основателей StackOverflow) про закон дырявых абстракций.

Comment: @Герман Борисов Спасибо. Хорошая статья. "Это парадоксально, но с каждым разом, когда мы изобретаем все более высокоуровневые инструменты с более качественными абстракциями, становиться профессиональным программистом все сложнее." "Так что абстракции экономят нам время работы, но не время на обучение." Да. Главное - знать те абстракции, с которыми работаешь.

Comment: Вопрос стал закрыт до моего ответа, поэтому не смог ответить развернуто. По своему опыту скажу, что чем больше знаний, тем лучше, но главное, чтобы эти знания можно было применить, иначе они будут забыты. Те же знания UML, принципов ООП, разницу между языками (но только если программируете на разных языках или стоит вопрос о выборе языка). Для чего эти знания? Они упрощают понимание, с помощью этих знаний написана техническая литература, которая позволяет расти программисту профессионально.

Comment: Я очень долго не пользовался этими знаниями, а когда я начал пользоваться, понял, как много я потерял. Потому что эти знания упрощают жизнь программисту. Знания без применения равны нулю. Можно знать UML, но никогда не пользоваться ими, можно знать определения ООП, но понимать их неправильно или не уметь применять их.

Comment: "Выдавать что-то полезное" можно и без этих знаний, но каждый раз будут одни и те же проблемы, о которых программисты даже не задумываются. Об этом говорится во многих книгах связанных с проектированием и архитектурой программного обеспечения. Можно написать много рабочего кода, который будет выполнять полезную работу, но когда этот код придется кому-то править или расширять, то появятся проблемы. Вот тогда и будут полезными все те знания, чтобы быстро что-то поправить или расширить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На мой взгляд (тоже 30 лет практики), программирование - настолько разнообразная область, что никаких универсальных рецептов тут быть не может. Да, если рассматривать то, как всё должно быть в идеале, то начинающий программист должен выучить дофига всякого, чтобы только начать что-то делать: структуры данных, алгоритмы, ООП, правила хорошего оформления кода, научиться эффективно пользоваться средами разработки, быстрому поиску ответов на вопросы в интернете, ... да полно всего можно ещё вписать сюда. Но в реальности так не бывает. Начинают программировать всегда с очень малым запасом теории, постепенно расширяя знания в процессе работы. Причём, разные области программирования требуют довольно разной степени теоретической подготовки. Одно дело масштабный проект писать, где участвует много людей и без глубоких знаний невозможно сделать так, чтобы вся эта махина взлетела. И другое дело какой-нибудь простенький сайт, где можно наколхозить чего-нибудь на Java Script без особых знаний. И ещё много промежуточных вариантов и вариантов из других областей программирования.

Поэтому на мой взгляд нужно составлять требования к программистам под ваш конкретный проект и под конкретные позиции. Что обычно и делается, когда нанимают людей. Есть определённые требования - знать то-то и то-то, кандидат ищется и тестируется на знание этих вещей. А универсальных рецептов тут нет и быть не может. Программисты разные нужны. Кому-то в проекте нужны мощные универсалы, знающие практически всё и способные написать что угодно и у него есть на них деньги. А кому-то нужны чисто кодеры "числом поболее, ценою подешевле", чтобы за копейки "копали отсюда и до забора", клепая простенькие сайты или не знаю там что ещё простое делали, главное "бери больше, кидай дальше", а что конкретно - progect manager объяснит.

Никакого универсального рецепта тут просто нет. Жизнь - штука сложная и разнообразная. :)